# SQL query over 2 different tables for some common value grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 tables, one for student/class & the other for student/interests as below, for example;

```
studentID   class
---------------------
4134              1
4135              1
4136              1
4137              1
4138              2
4139              2
4140              2
4141              2

studentID   interests
---------------------
4134        basketball
4134        football
4135        basketball
4136        basketball
4137        football
4138        swimming
4138        football
4139        running
4140        tennis
4141        tennis
```

What will be the best way to query about which students have same interests with his classmates ONLY? The hardest part is the requirement of ONLY.

The query should not result in 4135, 4136, 4140 & 4141. As even 4134 has same interest with 4137, both of their interests are same as 4138, who is not in class 1.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried to do to solve the problem.

Comment: If you can create a simple sqlfiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with what you've got, you'll get better responses.

Comment: Also, based on your sample data please provide (add to your post) the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I have created two table for your data -

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (id INT , class INT)
CREATE TABLE #temp2 (id INT, activity VARCHAR(500))
```

```
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT 4134 ,             1   UNION ALL
SELECT 4135 ,             1   UNION ALL
SELECT 4136 ,             1   UNION ALL
SELECT 4137 ,             1   UNION ALL
SELECT 4138 ,             2   UNION ALL
SELECT 4139 ,             2   UNION ALL
SELECT 4140 ,             2   UNION ALL
SELECT 4141 ,             2
```

INSERT INTO #temp2
SELECT 4134 ,      'basketball'        UNION ALL
SELECT 4134 ,      'football'        UNION ALL
SELECT 4135 ,      'basketball'        UNION ALL
SELECT 4136 ,      'basketball'        UNION ALL
SELECT 4137 ,      'football'        UNION ALL
SELECT 4138 ,      'swimming'        UNION ALL
SELECT 4138 ,      'football'        UNION ALL
SELECT 4139 ,      'running'        UNION ALL
SELECT 4140 ,      'tennis'        UNION ALL
SELECT 4141 ,      'tennis'

AND use select statement

```
    SELECT DISTINCT t.id id
    FROM   #temp2 t
    INNER JOIN #temp2 t1 ON  t.activity = t1.activity AND t.id <> t1.id 
    INNER JOIN #temp t3 ON t.id = t3.id 
    INNER JOIN #temp t4 ON t1.id = t4.id
    WHERE t3.class = t4.class  AND t.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT te.id id 
       FROM   #temp2 te
       INNER JOIN #temp2 te1 ON  te.activity = te1.activity AND te.id <> te1.id 
       INNER JOIN #temp te3 ON te.id = te3.id 
       INNER JOIN #temp te4 ON te1.id = te4.id
       WHERE te3.class <> te4.class)
```

This will return -

```
id
4135
4136
4140
4141
```

Comment: Oops!! i wrote query for SQL server. But you can do same for Oracle. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have amended the question, which now will match what I actually need. As I said the hardest part is the ONLY requirement. If in java I can loop over to see whether those students are in same class but in SQL I do not know how to do it. Any help or hint will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You mean to say query should return 4135, 4136, 4140 & 4141 or it should not return? Can you also give expected result set? It should be easy. But still i didn't get what is your expected result set.

Comment: It should only return 4135,4136,4140 & 4141. The reason not returning 4134 & 4137 is they have same interests that someone from a different class has. Thanks

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check it, if you haven't got the answer yet. There could be other way too.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried writing query using joins and partition by just have a look at it

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT STUD_ID,CLASS,INTREST,COUNT(INTREST) OVER(partition BY INTREST) AS RR FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) OVER( PARTITION BY A.STUD_ID ) CN, B.STUD_ID,A.CLASS,B.INTREST FROM
STUDENTS A
JOIN
INTREST B
ON
A.STUD_ID = B.STUD_ID )
 WHERE CN =1 )WHERE RR >1 ;
```